# After installing Pimcore demo i cannot enter /admin

Tags: pimcore

So i'm trying to install Pimcore to my local environment.

I followed the steps at: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Getting_Started/Installation.html

The install wen't fine with just one error about running a sql:  * An exception occurred while executing 'DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PLUGIN_CMF_COLLECT_ASSET_SEGMENT_ASSIGNMENTS;

I did fix that by logging in to mysql as root and executed the query described from this: https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/4526

So, all installed i went to my browser and localhost. The Pimcore demo page loads, but with no images. And i'm not able to enter /admin. the page doesn't excist.

I have googled around for hours and read about filepermissions, so i set the pimcore project folder to rw for all users.

When i check the project folder i have no "web" folder or "admin" folder..

So where should i look next?
Should there be an admin folder in my project root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be in httpd.conf

user _www (had to be my personal account)
group _www (had to be staff)

Also i have missed the AllowOverride All setting.

Answer (score 3):

One more important thing, that is missing in pimcore installation guide.
It looks like the **installation doesn't create the .htaccess** file in

```
your-project/public/.htaccess
```

I have created .htaccess according to:

https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Apache_Configuration.html

Make sure that `Allowoverride All` is set for your the `DocumentRoot`, in your VHOSTS settings - it is needed for `.htaccess` support.

```
<Directory /var/www/<your-domain>/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*public is public directory in pimcore installation folder.

And now it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as a result of being sloppy..

Running on FreeBSD 13.1 with Apache 2.4 and PHP 8.1 with Composer 2, I made several attempts to install both the demo and the skeleton with the exact same outcome as this question poses.

The reason it failed was that I ran the installation as root. SU to the web service user - probably www - and try again.

Edit: I'd like to add that the installation instructions for Pimcore skips a crucial step for the installation. To a salty PHP developer, this is probably obvious, but for anyone else - after you run "composer create-project pimcore/demo my-project", enter the "my-project" folder (or whatever you chose to name it) and run "composer install".